# Issue with ajax while using Spring3 mvc. Getting a 406 error while returning a list of objects

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, jackson

I get tried implement ajax in my spring3 mvc application. Ajax worked fine when I was returning a simple string but when I tried returning a list of strings I got a `406 error`.

This is my `context` file

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ajaxtest" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

This is my controller mapping method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
        headers="Accept=*/*")
public @ResponseBody List<String> testAjax(@RequestParam("query") String query) {
    System.out.println(query);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add(""+i);
    }
    return list;
}
```

This is my js code.

```
$(function(){
    $.get('ajax/test.html',{'query' : 1},function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I have added the following jar files for mapping.

`jackson-core-2.0.2.jar, jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar, jackson-datatype-json-org-2.0.2.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar`

What changes should I do to return a list of objects back to js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP Error Code 406 stands for Bad Client Request (see [HTTP error codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code#4xx_Client_Error))

> The requested resource is only capable of generating content not
>   acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.

You need to set the Accept Header to `application/json`. In JQuery, you do that by using [`jQuery.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)